# How to give parameters to a function that is given as a parameter value for query-params?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I can write:

```
{{#link-to 'route' (query-params color=getColor)}}
    Link
{{/link-to}}
```

Is there any way to give parameters to getColor function? getColor is defined in the corresponding controller.

Comment: Did you try to create a getColor computed property on the controller which returns the function?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that. Query parameters are already subexpressions, there's no way to nest yet another one. (That would just make for horribly unreadable code). You're going to have to create a computed property that returns the value you want, as enspandi said in the comments.